# How center popover on TableView?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, popover

I'm make a tableview with a button in every cell, when you push the button shows a popover, but the problem is a make the popover to center over the tableview, but if you go down the tableView, and push the button the popover use as guideline the select button, so the popover go up. On the next images you can see what I trying to explain.

[image]

The code used when you press the button from the cell:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){

    let buttonTag = sender.tag

    let width = self.view.frame.midX + (self.view.frame.midX/2)

    let height = info[buttonTag].nota.calculateHeight(width: width, sizeFont: 16.0) + 40

    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotaTable") as! Popever

    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height + 115)
    vc.width = width

    let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.delegate = self
    popover.sourceView = self.view

    popover.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX - (width/2), y: self.view.frame.midY - (height/2), width: width, height: height)

    popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

    present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)

}
```

So, How do I make the popover to focus on center no matter what button press?

Thanks advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the way to solve this, changing the popover.sourceRect, instead
 of completing de x and y position with self.view.frame replaced for self.view.bounds

```
let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.delegate = self
    popover.sourceView = self.view

    popover.sourceRect = CGRect(x: (self.view.bounds.midX - (width/2)), y: (self.view.bounds.midY - (height/2)), width: width, height: height)
```

Here I leave you the difference between frame and bounds:

The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system (0,0).

The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained within.

[I got it from here](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/frame-vs-bounds)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `Table View bounds` to the popover frame view. For more details please see the code below.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
    let popOver = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MSGPopupController") as! MSGPopupController
    self.addChildViewController(popOver)
    popOver.view.frame = self.tableView.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(popOver.view)
    popOver.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

But keep in mind your table is still scrollable. with popup. For removing this issue you have to use protocols like.

> Before opening the pop up just add `self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false` and set delegate `popOver.msg_delegate = self`.

Then your complete code will be

```
 func message_pop_up(message : String)  {
    self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
    let popOver = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MSGPopupController") as! MSGPopupController
    popOver.msg_delegate = self
    self.addChildViewController(popOver)
    popOver.view.frame = self.tableView.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(popOver.view)
    popOver.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Delegate class like

```
extension Your_Current_Controller : MSGPopupDelegate {
func ok_click() {
    self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
  }
}
```

And your `MSGPopupController` should be like that with protocols. Else you can change it on the basis if your requirement.

```
import UIKit
protocol MSGPopupDelegate {
   func ok_click()
}
class MSGPopupController: UIViewController {  
@IBOutlet weak var tf_title: UILabel!  // This is taken from My View 
@IBOutlet weak var tf_message: UILabel! // This is taken from My View
@IBOutlet weak var btn_close_ot: UIButton! // This is taken from My View

var message_text : String!

var msg_delegate : MSGPopupDelegate! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    self.showAnimation()
    
    tf_message.text = message_text!
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
// This is taken from My View
@IBAction func btn_close(_ sender: UIButton) {
    removeAnimation()
    if msg_delegate != nil {
        msg_delegate.ok_click()
    }
}

func showAnimation(){
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    })
}

func removeAnimation(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {(finished : Bool) in
        if(finished){
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }})
  }
}
```